# Convert datetime to string with month name and day name

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way to convert a `datetime` like **1/28/2016** to **Friday January 28 2016** in `C#`?

I'm using `.ToShortDateString()` to remove the time. I just want the date.

Comment: Why does it have to be .ToShortDateString()?

Comment: well, disregard the ToShortDateString() method. I'm just using it to shorten it without the time.

Comment: This is pretty easy stuff to research...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`DateTime.ToLongDateString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) function, it is designed to fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.ToLongDateString()` instead. For example:

```
DateTime myDateTime = new System.DateTime(2001, 5, 16, 3, 2, 15);
Console.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToLongDateString());
```

This will output *"Wednesday, May 16, 2001"* to the console window.

Answer (score 3):

While converting date to string you can set its format

```
someDate.ToString("dddd MMMM d yyyy");
```

should give you format you need.

```
.ToLongDateString()
```

should also work, but it doesn't give you customization capabilities.

You can find out more about date formatting here: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)